# PHP - Calculate next date interval for reminder

Tags: php, date

I am creating reminders. I need to calculate the next date given a frequency and start date. Frequencies can be *weekly*, *monthly*, *quarterly*, *annually*.

The following code is a start:

```
$date = new DateTime($start_date);
switch ($frequency) {
    case: 'weekly'
        $interval = 'P1W';
        break;
    case: 'monthly'
        $interval = 'P1M';
        break;
    case: 'quarterly'
        $interval = 'P3M';
        break;
    case: 'annually'
        $interval = 'P1Y';
        break;
}

$date->add(new DateInterval($interval));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

The problem is `$start_date` may be in the distant past.

For example, if `$start_date` is `2014-04-01` and the frequency is `weekly` the reminder will be created in the past for `2014-04-08`.

I need to add logic to ensure the reminder is created for the next interval in the future.

I thought about determining the recent date by determining the day of `$start_date` for the interval, then adding the interval.

Should be straightforward, but it's the end of a long day. Would appreciate some insight from the community.

Comment: Why is this required? You're always *adding* to the given date, so why  would it be set in the past?

Comment: `$start_date` is the date of the *original* reminder. So I'm not *always* adding. Sometimes I'm creating (or restarting) a reminder from a `$start_date` in the distant past.

Comment: Does the downvoter care to share?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this after your switch statement:

```
$curdate = new DateTime('today');
$interval = new DateInterval($interval);
do {
    $date->add($interval);
} while ($date <= $curdate);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

<kbd>[**demo**](https://eval.in/137238)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks. This definitely works. I was holding out for something more elegant (i.e. not a loop).

Comment: +1. Ah. Only now did I understand the actual question.

Comment: @Amal Murali, I left a comment. Didn't realize you still weren't understanding.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: No worries. I'm glad you got your problem resolved :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you pretty much the right idea with this :

```
I thought about determining the recent date by determining the day of $start_date for the interval, then adding the interval.
```

You could use a nice little recursive function to do all that for you, like this

```
<?php

    $frequency = 'weekly';
    $last_date_we_have = '2014-01-02';

    $valid_reminder_date = get_next_reminder_date($last_date_we_have, $frequency);

    echo ' Next valid reminder date = ' . $valid_reminder_date;
    exit;

function get_next_reminder_date($start_date, $frequency)
{
    $date = new DateTime($start_date);
    switch ($frequency) {
        case 'weekly' :
            $interval = 'P1W';
            break;
        case 'monthly' :
            $interval = 'P1M';
            break;
        case 'quarterly' :
            $interval = 'P3M';
            break;
        case 'annually' :
            $interval = 'P1Y';
            break;
    }

    $date->add(new DateInterval($interval));

    if ( time() > $date->getTimestamp() ) {
        echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
        echo ' Not there yet' . PHP_EOL;
        return get_next_reminder_date($date->format('Y-m-d'), $frequency);
    } else {
        return $date->format('Y-m-d');
    }
}
```

With the input in the example the results are:

```
2014-01-09 Not there yet
2014-01-16 Not there yet
2014-01-23 Not there yet
2014-01-30 Not there yet
2014-02-06 Not there yet
2014-02-13 Not there yet
2014-02-20 Not there yet
2014-02-27 Not there yet
2014-03-06 Not there yet
2014-03-13 Not there yet
2014-03-20 Not there yet
2014-03-27 Not there yet
2014-04-03 Not there yet
2014-04-10 Not there yet
Next valid reminder date = 2014-04-17
```